# How to import multiple components and classes in a single line - angular?

Tags: angular, import

I have the following doubt:

I am creating an angular application and I have designed several common components that can be used in any part of the application, however, there are approximately 15, plus the classes that contain the templates or forms.

The downside I have had is that component and model imports have become quite tedious and I was wondering if there is any way in which I can import all the components and models of the common components that I have created without having to import them all?

Example: I would like to skip this

```
import { ComponentGeneric_2 } from './common-component/component-generic-2.component';
import { ComponentGeneric_3 } from './common-component/component-generic-3.component';
import { ComponentGeneric_4 } from './common-component/component-generic-4.component';
import { ComponentGeneric_5 } from './common-component/component-generic-5.component';
import { ComponentGeneric_6 } from './common-component/component-generic-6.component';
import { ComponentGeneric_7 } from './common-component/component-generic-7.component';
```

And let it be replaced by this

```
import { CommonComponents } from './common-component/generic.xxx';
```

Answer (score 0):

index.ts

```
 export * from './common-component/component-generic-2.component';
 export * from './common-component/component-generic-3.component';
 export * from './common-component/component-generic-4.component';
```

home.component.ts

```
import { CommonComponent1,CommonComponent2  } from './common-component/index.ts';
```

or else if you specified paths in tsconfig.json like this,

```
 "paths": {
  "@components/*": [
    "./src/app/common-component/*"
  ]
 }
```

use can import components like this,

```
 import { CommonComponent1,CommonComponent2  } from '@components';
```

Comment: Thanks Tony, both solutions allowed me to resolve the question. I will use the second one above all (using the tsconfig.json file), since in case of adding more components, these will be included directly

Comment: happy to here that :)